# FLEX 4: importing html in spark with textarea TextConverter

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flex-spark

I have imported a Html text into textarea using Textconverter and it works well, but I have a problem
I need to mark with "image not found" if and image inside into imported html isn't more online or simply don't exist, so if anybody can help me...

Thanks

es.

```
            var string:String = '<img src="elvis.gif" />';
            aTextArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(string, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an option that comes out of the box with TLF.

If I were you, I would check first if the image exists using URLLoader.
If it doesn't exist, replace your img tag in your string with an error message.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this will mean:
- parse html and find img tag
- then replace tag with "image not found/ not online"
- and import in textArea

Comment: Yes, that's how I would do it